# Cannot use JQuery Plugin TableSorter with underscore

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, tablesorter

I am creating a table comparable to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/aPv9H/1/

```
<head>
<script type="text/html" id='usageList'>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1' >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% _.each(items,function(item,key,list){ 
        // create more variables
        var f = item.name.split("").shift().toLowerCase(); 
    %>
        <tr>
            <!-- use variables -->
            <td><%= key %></td>
            <td class="<%= f %>"><%= item.name %></td>
        </tr>
    <% }); %>
</tbody>
</table>
</script>

<script>
var items = [
    {name:"Alexander"},
    {name:"Barklay"},
    {name:"Chester"},
    {name:"Domingo"},
    {name:"Edward"},
    {name:"..."},
    {name:"Yolando"},
    {name:"Zachary"}
];

var template = $("#usageList").html();
$("#target").html(_.template(template,{items:items}));


$('table').tablesorter({
    // include zeba widgets
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    // initial sort
    sortList: [[0, 0], [2, 0]]
});

$('table').bind('sortBegin', function(e, tbl) {
    var c = tbl.config,
        list = c.sortList;
    // add date sort if not the initial sort, otherwise sort second column
    // (zero based index)
    list.push((list[0] && list[0][0] !== 2) ? [2, 0] : [1, 0]);
});
</script>
</head>

<!-- Create your target -->
<body>
<div id="target"></div>

</body>
```

in order to use the template functionality to populate the table.

However, I attempted to add the jquery plugin TableSorter, and this doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone have an example that does?

I get no errors, however nothing happens.

Thanks.

Comment: How does it not work? Errors?

Comment: I don't see where you are using the tablesorter plugin.

Comment: I was hoping that someone could post a very simple working example...

Comment: you should include the code where you use tablesorter plugin and it fails

Comment: @Jerry Provide the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the jQuery code itself isn't wrapped in a document ready function. So it doesn't see the `#target` div....

```
$(function(){
    // all the script goes here
});
```

jsFiddle wraps the code automatically for you, so it's easy to miss... it can be changed by using the bottom select box ("onLoad" by default) within the "Frameworks & Extensions" accordion panel.

[image]

---

Update: Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/aPv9H/273/)):

```
$(function(){
    var items = [
            {name:"Alexander"},
            {name:"Barklay"},
            {name:"Chester"},
            {name:"Domingo"},
            {name:"Edward"},
            {name:"..."},
            {name:"Yolando"},
            {name:"Zachary"}
        ];

    var template = $("#usageList").html();
    $("#target")
        .html(_.template(template,{items:items}))
        .find('table').tablesorter();
});
```

Comment: Can someone please show me an example of the two tools working together?  That is what I am asking for...  There are issues it this example, I know that.  The original code is many pages of html and javascript, so I tried to distill it down.  My issue, I believe, is that with many examples of underscore and javascript functions, the underscore template cannot be serialized, as noted in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612576/jquery-event-inside-a-underscore-js-template
But, it seems to be more confusing when it is not your code you are using.

Comment: Thank you.  I am going to validate this in my code, but your example was successful.  Thanks.